# Uploading file using Multer in Nuxt 3 with Mongodb error: Unexpected end of form

Tags: nuxt.js, multer, nuxt3

I am having an issue when I'm trying to upload and save data into Mongodb and upload files using Multer. I was able to upload the files but when I insert a `readMultipartFormData` I am getting an `Unexpected end of form` error, and vice versa, when I remove the upload listener `callNodeListener` I am able to parse the data from the event which is `readMultipartFormData`.
I may have missed something. And by the way, I am using Nuxt 3 server and not Express. Any support or suggestion would be appreciated.

I'm using:

```json
"nuxt": "^3.4.1"
"mongoose": "^7.0.3",
"multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
```

Front-end upload

```js
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("testcase_data", JSON.stringify(testCaseFormData.value));
  for (var x = 0; x < selectedFiles.value.length; x++) {
  formData.append("images", selectedFiles.value[x]);
 }
  return await $fetch("/api/testcase/put", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
 });
```

Server

```js
import TestCaseModel from "~~/server/models/TestCase.model";
import multer from "multer";
import { callNodeListener, readRawBody } from "h3";
import path from "path";

let filePath: string = "N/A";
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  const uniqueSuffix = Date.now(); //  + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
  let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
  let baseName = path.basename(file.originalname, ext);
  if (baseName.length > 5) {
  baseName = baseName.substring(0, 5);
    }
  filePath = baseName + "-" + uniqueSuffix + ext;
  cb(null, filePath);
  },
});

const upload: any = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
  file.mimetype == "image/png" ||
  file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||
  file.mimetype == "image/gif"
    ) {
  cb(null, true);
    } else {
  cb(new Error("File type not supported"));
    }
  },
});

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body: any = await readMultipartFormData(event);


  try {
  // Update test case
  await TestCaseModel.findByIdAndUpdate(body._id, body);

// save data to mongodb
// await TestCaseModel.findByIdAndUpdate(body._id, body);

  // upload listener
  await callNodeListener(upload.array("images", 5), event.node.req, event.node.res);


  return { message: "Test case updated successfully" };
  } catch (e) {
  throw createError({
  statusCode: 422,
  statusMessage: "Unprocessable Entity",
  message: "Error while updating Test Case: " + e,
    });
  }
});
```

Workaround with Formidable

```js
import TestCaseModel from "~~/server/models/TestCase.model";
import FileModel from "~~/server/models/File.model";
import { readFiles } from "h3-formidable";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { fields, files } = await readFiles(event, {
    includeFields: true,
    // other formidable options below
    multiples: true,
    uploadDir: "./public/uploads",
    keepExtensions: true,
  });
  const body = JSON.parse(fields.testcase[0]);
  const body_files: any = files.images;
  let imagesArray: any[] = [];
  if (body_files && body_files.length > 0) {
    body_files.forEach((img: any) => {
      imagesArray.push({
        path: img.newFilename,
        mimetype: img.mimetype,
        test_case: body._id,
      });
    });
  }

  try {
    const uploadedFiles = await FileModel.insertMany(imagesArray);
    await TestCaseModel.findByIdAndUpdate(body._id, body).then((res) => {
      return TestCaseModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
        body._id,
        { $push: { files: { $each: uploadedFiles } } },
        { upsert: true }
      );
    });
    return { message: "Test Case updated successfully" };
  } catch (e) {
    throw createError({
      //   message: e.message,
      message: "Error while updating Test Case: " + e,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I just want to ask if you already solved it?

Comment: I end up actually using `formidable v3` and `h3-formidable` to take advantage of `readFiles`. You can refer on my workaround located in my question. I'm still open for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

### Upload file using multer module only.

`~/server/api/upload/index.post.ts`

```js
import multer from 'multer'
import {
  callNodeListener
} from 'h3'

let originalFileName = ''
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'public/assets/images')
  },
  filename: (req, file, cbd) => {
    originalFileName = file.originalname
    cbd(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
      cb(null, true)
    } else {
      cb(new Error('Invalid file type'))
    }
  }
})

export default defineEventHandler(async(event) => {
  try {
    // @ts-expect-error: Nuxt 3
    await callNodeListener(upload.single('file'), event.node.req, event.node.res)
    const path = `/assets/images/${originalFileName}`
    return path
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return createError({
      statusCode: 500,
      statusMessage: 'Something went wrong.'
    })
  }
})
```

**Note:** There will be an expected error on `callNodeListener` for typescript.

If the upload is successful it will return the file path. You can do whatever you want with the file path.

Ensure to create a folder inside the `public` folder. `~/public/assets/images`

Client-side `~app.vue`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const file = ref<File | string>('')
const newlyUploadedFile = ref<string>('')
const handleFileChange = (fileData: Event) => {
  const fileInputData = (fileData.target as HTMLInputElement)
  if (fileInputData.files && fileInputData.files?.length > 0) {
    file.value = fileInputData.files[0]
  }
}

const handleFileUpload = async () => {
  console.log(file)
  const body = new FormData();
  body.append('file', file.value);
  await useFetch('/api/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body,
    onResponse(context) {
      newlyUploadedFile.value = context.response._data
    }
  })
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      name="file"
      type="file"
      @change="handleFileChange"
    />
    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <button @click.prevent="handleFileUpload">Upload File</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img :src="newlyUploadedFile" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <pre>Check the '~/public/assets/images'</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
img {
  width: 500px;
}
</style>
```

I created a working example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-fbp4pn?file=app.vue

Note: When testing it on stackblitz, it might take a while to upload the file in the stackblitz. But, if you test it on the local machine it should work.
[image]

#### Edit:

#### Upload multiple files

Here is an example of uploading multiple files and stored the paths to mongoDB.
https://github.com/ReaganM02/Nuxt3-Upload-Multiple-Files-To-MongoDB

Comment: I actually need to handle the data that are appended in `formData`. Your solution is only uploading images.

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure what you are referring to. What does the 'appended in formData' mean?

Comment: This works, this should be an accepted answer since the OP ask a question on uploading files. Thanks!