# Nuxt 3 with useFetch File Upload becomes empty object on server side why

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have created a form having below fields

```
const formData = ref({
  title: undefined,
  categories: [],
  pimage: undefined
})
```

To handle image i have below function

```
const handleImageUpload = (event) => {
  formData.value.pimage = event.target.files[0];
};
```

Now i am sending data to backend

```
const { data } = await useFetch('apiurl/create/', { method: 'post', body: formData.value })
```

Everything works fine i console.log to check *formData.value* which outputs all data title, categories and pimage.
but the same pimage becomes empty object on server side In the server i am using Django Rest and pimage become `{ }`
Why is that and How can fix it ? Its definitely not server side issue as when i send same data using `FormData()` which requires to `append()` each field i am able to get pimage but then my categories are no longer an array it becomes string which is not ideal for my project. So i have to use formData.value Please help me to fix it. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi, your question might be related to this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76101115/21341655

Comment: @ReaganM Link suggested by you have used FormData() which is not ideal for my project because it makes categories field as string which supposed to be remain an array. FormData() is good option to send string and file but not other type of data.